# Are there any measurements of the performance hit incurred from global namespace pollution in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, window, javascript-namespaces, global-namespace

One of the first things I learned when writing JavaScript was that it bad practice to set variables on `window` and polluting the global namespace.

Looking around there are loads of articles as there are SO questions on why it is considered bad practice and even how to measure the amount of objects stored ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039217/measuring-pollution-of-global-namespace)).

But even if I can get the amount of objects being stored on `window` I have never read anything about the actual performance hit taken by cluttering `window`.

**Question**:
Are there any examples showing how name space pollution drains performance?

Comment: There is a performance hit, but IMO the bigger issue is name conflicts. Often if your code is large enough to have performance issues from this, it is large enough to be very difficult to avoid name clashes.

Comment: Good point. Still curious if there is any "evidence"

Comment: I imagine it is browser dependent. You could try fiddling with these and see what you get: [with namespace pollution](http://jsperf.com/global-namespace-pollution), [without namespace pollution](http://jsperf.com/global-namespace-pollution/2)

Comment: I modified it a little. So you have your [2nd revision ("no pollution")](jsperf.com/global-namespace-pollution/2/) and my [3rd revision ("polluted")](http://jsperf.com/global-namespace-pollution/3). Your first test was tainted because you were picking a value from your `window[array]` vs declaring a variable. What do you think?

Comment: I think it is interesting to note the difference between low and high when a lot of keys are present. Also, it seems to be about a 2x difference in ops/sec between the two tests here.

Comment: Yup. I will later try a similar thing with more realistic setup = one revision with plugins like ... jQuery, jQuery Mobile... The other one without. This would be a more realistic scenario.